# fs.readFileSync throwing errno 4058

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I try to access the json file iike this:

```
...
var configurationFile = fileSystem.readFileSync(
  "../configurationFile.json"
);
var apiSecretKey = JSON.parse(configurationFile.toString()).secret;
var url = JSON.parse(configurationFile.toString()).db_url;
var dbName = JSON.parse(configurationFile.toString()).db_name;
...
```

i get this error

```
   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../configurationFile.json'
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\GitHub\project-1\Back-End\API\Services\loginservice.js:7:36)
   ...
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\GitHub\project-1\Back-End\index.js:11:26) {
   errno: -4058,
   syscall: 'open',
   code: 'ENOENT',
   path: '../configurationFile.json'
```

this is the dir structure

API

...Services

......loginservice.js

...configurationFile.js

index.js

How do i get around this besides this wrapping the config in a module. Is this a windows specific issue?

Comment: As mentioned in the error, it's not able to find the file in the location provided. Please make sure that `configurationFile.json` is available in the specified location

Comment: It is there, I have updated the question with its location within the dir, also it works when I wrap it in a module and require it.

Comment: Are you reading the file from `index.js`?  And also is `configurationFile.js` and `index.js` in the same directory?

Comment: I am reading from both, login service is  an express router and the code snippet is from there, in index I tried to extract the port no and hostname in the same manner.

Comment: Okay, As per directory structure mentioned in the question, The file name is mentioned as `configurationFile.js` and in code you are calling `configurationFile.json`. Is it a typo in the question?

Comment: Typo.  Sorry. It is Json(I have converted to a module , I forgot the context.)